# How to proced after ejabberd got installed?

Tags: dns, xmpp, ejabberd

After I have installed Ejabberd (latest version), I tried to test It with Psi, I got always an error "CAN'T CONNECT TO SERVER", after some googling and githubing the issue, I have found that after installing ejabberd I should add some certificates (TLS/SSL DNS records I think), this is what I didn't do, and I don't know how to do that, It's pretty hard(since I'm new to this tech).

Is there any one got the same issue, if true how did you solve it.

**Note**:I'm running ejabberd & Psi on the same machine, Windows 10

Comment: on your development machine, you can use self-signed SSL certificate. On your production server, you can either use purchase an SSL certificate from authorised CA or you can generate it using Let's Encrypt certbot - https://certbot.eff.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ejabberd binary installers (at least the 18.12 linux installer) includes a self-signed certificate. Check your configuration file, and probably it already has the certificate configured, and something like this:

```
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: true
```

Remember to tell your client to use encryption (probably already enabled). Also, tell your client where the server is: In Psi, go to Account Setup -> Modify -> Connection -> Manually Specify Server Host/Port: 127.0.0.1 Port: 5222.

That wouldn't be necessary if you configure properly DNS.

Comment: Yeah, It works now, I have also added SRV certificate(self signed),this configured manually, but what I can do if I have my own xmpp client. I think I should study this more